# Generating sections from C code for ARM (Keil uVIsion) and get beginning and ending symbols, and prevent the linker to remove them

Tags: c, linker, arm, symbols, sections

I'm developing an embedded project for ARM in C. I want to create a section in code in which I define some functions and then an `init` function will iterate over them to execute them. Something like:

```
void f1(void) { ... } __section("some_section")
void f2(void) { ... } __section("some_section")
...
...
[In a different module]

typedef void (*funptr)(void);

void init_func(void) {
  funptr iter = &__some_section_start;
  do {
     *iter();
      iter++;
  } while (iter <= &__some_section_end);
}
```

I'm aware of something like this can be done by modifying the project linker script, but **I want to know if it is possible to do so without linker scripts.**

I have tried as well `__attribute__((section("ARM.at.<address>")))` but that won't work because that would make one function to overlap the other.

In addition, I have tried to use a typical `__attribute__((section(...)))` and dissasembly the generated file, to see if the Keil compiler generates any sort of symbol to indicate the beginning and end of the section. Not only it doesn't do that, many times the variable I have created in a particular section is just not generated. I suspect the linker is striping it out, even using `volatile` and `attribute(used)` (which is supposed to do exactly this). **How can I prevent the linker to do this?**

Comment: You can declare an extern const array of function pointers, and call them in your init function, while you initialize the array in some file. If the space to store the pointers are too costly, running optimizations should be able to inline the calls, especially if they are const. A small example: https://godbolt.org/z/ecjrYxG5b

Comment: You can declare `__some_section_start` and `__some_section_end` as `extern void*` and use them. However, I see no way to create a reliable iterator. The section collects all machine code for the functions, but AFAIK without any size information. -- Your best bet is to create a table of function pointers and iterate through it. For this you don't even need a separated section.

Comment: @busybee yes but then the problem is that I can't do that at build time, I can only declare functions. I mean, I could manually assign these functions to the table, but I wanted a solution that doesn't involve that. What I have done for know is create several `__weak` functions so I can overwrite them at link time, but this has a number of problems.

Comment: Don't you want to have an section of function pointers, not a section of functions? `I could manually assign these functions to the table`  What do you mean by "manually"? Yes, you manually put the function pointers into the section, but it's the same way you "manually" have a put a function definition there.

Comment: @KamilCuk By manually I mean that I need to go to the list of functions and add the new function manually. I want to avoid that and instead create a macro, e.g.: `SYS_INIT(function)`, that adds a function to the above list, at build time, without the need for modifying manually external modules.

Comment: Yes, and typically that is solved with array of _function pointers_, not array of functions. But, anyway, overall my advice: _do not_ do that. Do not use some non-portable specific syntax and do not use sections. Do not avoid coding. Do not hide stuff. Do not write spaghetti code. Yes, reference all functions in one place.

Comment: @KamilCuk I know it sounds kind of a bad practice, but for instance this is the system used by zephyr OS (with SYS_INIT, DEVICE_INIT and the like).

Comment: Then, have you explored how `SYS_INIT` in zephyr works? It still does something different - it puts a structure `init_entry` into the section, _not_ function definitions. Does a following code: `int a __section("some_section"); extern void *__some_section_start; int main() { return &__some_section_start; }` compiles in Keil ARM compiler? Does keil linker support `__section_start` names? [This link](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlink/armlink_pge1362065958198.htm) looks interesting - does a code like `void *some_section$$Base; int main() { return &some_section$$Base; }` work?